# Increment number in Dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, casting

I have a Dictionary `[String:AnyObject]` which contains some keys and values.

I want to increment a key to which value is of type Double.

I can do it this way:

```
let nr = dict["number"] as! Double
dict["number"] = nr + 10
```

But I dont like that way so Im wondering if there is another way

I tried this:

```
(dict["number"] as! Double) += 10
```

But that gives me an error:

> Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type '(Double)' and 'Double'

Why isn't this working?

Comment: Your first solution is the cleanest and most readable solution for achieving what you want. Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: @DannyBravo I dont think thts wrong Im nostly curious why the second solution doesnt work. And I like single-line stuff :)

Comment: @DannyBravo And personally I think the second solution is cleaner and more readable when put into my other code.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not sure why the other option is not working for you, though.

Comment: The alternative is `dict["number"] = dict["number"]! + 10`

Comment: @Rob Fair enough :) Had to cast to Double though, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are close and in fact you can write to a dictionary using `+=`, the problem is your cast. For example we can do:

```
var dict = ["number" : 2]
dict["number"]! += 10
```

and now `dict["number"]` returns `12`. Now this is creating a new value (12) and replacing it into the dictionary, it is just a clean way of looking at it.

The problem with your code is that the left side `(dict["number"] as! Double)` gives you a `Double`. So you have say `(12)`, then the right side is a `Double` too (`10`). So your code ends up looking like `(12) += 10` which you can clearly see as problematic, since this is equivalent to `12 = 12 + 10`, yikes!

So that being said, you can use the my first solution if you are working with native Swift dictionaries, otherwise your solved solution above works too, just a bit longer.

Lastly, if you are really looking for a one liner that works with your exact situation you should be able to do something like:

```
dict["number"] = (dict["number"] as! Double) + 10
```

Comment: Thats why I was so confused because if its a [String:Double] I know I can increment like I want, guess this is the correct answer. Sorry @matt :(

Answer (score 13):

Following is an alternative. If you want to avoid force unwrapping an optional:

```
dict["number"] = (dict["number"] ?? 0) + 10
```

Comment: I'm growing to enjoy these sorts of shortcuts in Swift, after my years in C++.  Altho probably they're available in C++ now as well.

Answer (score 5):

Another option:

```
dict["number", default: 0] += 10
```

Answer (score 0):

The safe way of casting would be:

```
if let num = dict["number"] as? Double {
    dict["number"] = num + 10
}
```